# jquery validate dropdown doesnt work

Tags: jquery, validation

I can't make work the validation plugin when I try to validate a dropdown. And in chrome I am getting a warning message that it says:  "nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing "

```
$('#wpuf_form').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {

        "category[]" : {
            required:{
                depends: function(element){
                    return $('.cat').val() == '-1';
                    }
                }
            }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form){
        alert('test');
    }
 });

 <!-- this the html -->
 <form id="wpuf_form" name="wpuf_form" action=""  method="POST">
 <select name="category[]" id="cat" class="cat">
 <option value="-1">– Select –</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="1">test</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="2">test2</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="3">test3</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="wpuf_new_post_submit" value="Submit Creation">                        
 </form>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What, _specifically_, is not working???

Comment: Thanks Austin for looking at my code, I isolated the problem and edit my question and I checked twice and i got a warning message  "nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing " this message comes on chrome

Comment: I just solved my problem it is just the validate plugin doesnt like the value == '-1', I had to change it to value == '', I wish I could know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem it is just the validate plugin doesnt like the value == '-1', I had to change it to value == '', I wish I could know why... since i was using a wordpress function to do this i used javascript to change the value by default to cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].value = '';

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your validate code is added once the page is loaded and the #wpuf_form element exists.  To do this make sure it is included within a $('document').ready() statement;

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#wpuf_form').validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {

            "category[]" : {
                required:{
                    depends: function(element){
                        return $('.cat').val() == '-1';
                        }
                    }
                }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form){
            alert('test');
        }
     });
}
```